# Are the following examples of global variables?

Tags: javascript

I know that a global variable is a variable with global scope. I know that global scope means it can be seen by all. Does that mean, in `node.js`, that `n` here is a global variable?

```
let n = 1

function f() {}
...
```

I've also read that a global variable can be defined as a property of the global object e.g. `global.clearInterval`. `global.clearInterval` can be seen anywhere so has global scope. Is it right to call a property of the global object a global variable?

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean, in node.js, that `n` here is a global variable?

It depends on how you run it. By default, no, because Node.js treats your code as a **module**, not a **script**. Top-level declarations in modules aren't globals, they're scoped to the module.

If you were running that code as a **script**, then `n` (and `f`) would be global variables (although, amusingly, they're different *kinds* of global variables; more below). With Node.js, you can run code at global scope by feeding the code directly into Node.js instead of giving it a file to execute. So if you have:

`file.js`:

```js
function f() { }
console.log(global.f === f);
```

And you do this:

```
node file.js
```

you'll see `false`, because `f` isn't a global. But if you do:

```
node -e "function f() { } console.log(global.f === f);"
```

you'll see `true`, because code you pass in the `-e` ("eval") option is executed at global scope. (You can also do it from a file by redirecting the file into `node` instead of having `node` read the file directly: `node < file.js`.)

Note that `n` won't be a property of `global` either way, though, because it's a different kind of global.

> I've also read that a global variable can be defined as a property of the global object e.g. `global.clearInterval`. `global.clearInterval` can be seen anywhere so has global scope. Is it right to call a property of the global object a global variable?

Yes, mostly. That is: properties of the global object are global variables, but JavaScript actually has *two* kinds of global variables: Ones that are properties of the global object, and ones that aren't. At global scope, `var` and `function` declarations create global variables that are properties of the global object, but `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations create globals that *aren't* properties of the global object.

The global environment that uses the global object is the "outer" global environment. The one where identifiers created by using `let`, `const`, and `class` declarations at global scope is the "inner" global environment. That means that `let`/`const`/`class` globals shadow globals on the global object, just like local variables in a function shadow variables declared outside the function.

---

Side note: Beware that `global` is a Node.js-specific global not present in most other JavaScript environments. ES2020 adds a new predefined global, [`globalThis`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globalthis), which is the same value that `this` has at global scope (which, traditionally, refers to the global object), which takes the place of Node.js's `global`.

Comment: Thanks. So if `let n = 1` was on the console, it'd be considered a global variable because it's being treated as a script?

Comment: @tonitone111 - If you mean the Node.js console (REPL), yes. It's a global that isn't a property of the global object. `var n = 1;` would be a global that *is* a property of the global object.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the console tab in Browsers

Comment: Why are global variables important, what do they do? If they're just variables that can be accessed at any point in the file they're in, why is `let n` not considered a global variable in my text-editor even though it can be seen by everywhere in the file?

Comment: @tonitone111 - The value of a global is that it's accessible *everywhere*, not just in the file it's in. `parseInt` is a global, for instance, as is `Date`. It used to be that if you wanted other scripts to have access to something (for instance, `$` in jQuery or `_` in Underscore/lodash), you had to make it a global. But that leads to conflicts (such as between jQuery and PrototypeJS, back years ago). In general, you want to avoid global variables and JavaScript has been getting features to make that possible in the last several years (most notably: modules).

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean everywhere. For instance, if I add property `n` to the global object, in `Node.js`, with `n = 1` in file 'one.js', it's not like I can access `n` in file 'two.js'.

Comment: @tonitone111 - If you really make `n` a global, yes, you can.

Comment: @tonitone111 - Try this: `one.js`: `const {foo} = require("./two.js");
global.n = 0;
n = 1;
foo();` `two.js`: `exports.foo = function() {
 console.log(n); /* Shows 1 */
};` Note that `two.js` sees the global `n`.

Comment: So `one.js` invokes the function `foo` in `two.js` and `foo` is able to return `n`? Is it not strange how a simple `console.log(n)` in `two.js` complains `n` is not defined?

Comment: @tonitone111 - It doesn't have to be in a function, this works too: `one.js`: `global.n = 0;
n = 1;

require("./two.js");` `two.js`: `console.log(n); // 1` What's important is that the code in `one.js` has to create the global before the code in `two.js` can use it. Otherwise, of course, the global doesn't exist.

Comment: I found your answer really useful. Do you mind if I ask you what the significance of `let` `const` `class` being global variables in the console (of a browser) is? I know global variables mean they can be accessed everywhere but, for instance, I can't access a variable I make in the browser tab in a .js file (that is associated with that browser tab). Practically, what can we do with these global variables?

Comment: @tonitone111 - *"I can't access a variable I make in the browser tab in a .js file (that is associated with that browser tab)."* Yes, you can, in the normal case. You do have to get the timing right. If you're *creating* it in the console, you have to trigger your code in the JavaScript file *afterward*.